Topology: Linear Map and Interior
Do any of you know where I can find some information on the images of interiors of sets under linear maps?
Ok, so I am basically interested in
$$\phi[\text{relint}(A)]=\text{relint}(\phi[A])$$
where $\phi$ is a linear map $\phi:X\to X$ on a topological (linear) space and relint is the relative interior.
The other thing I would like to know is when given topological (linear) spaces $X,Y$ what do we know about continuity of (linear) maps $\phi_1:X\times Y\to X\times Y$ or $\phi_2:X\times Y\to X$, where on $X\times Y$ we consider the product topology?
I cannot find anything helpful for that.
For the first thing I think that $\phi[\text{relint}(A)]=\text{relint}(\phi[A])$ is correct, when $A$ is convex and $\text{relint}(A)\neq\emptyset$. This is based on some knowledge about algebraic properties - I have not really worked with topology yet.
For the second question I should go a bit more into detail: It is known that $\phi_1$ is continuous if and only if both projections $\text{proj}_X\circ\phi_1$ and $\text{proj}_Y\circ\phi_1$ are continuous (right?). What is for example with the following map: given any $z\in X$ and using $Y=\mathbb R$ we set $\Phi:X\times\mathbb R\to X\times\mathbb R$, $\Phi(x,t)=(x+tz,t)$. Since $X$ is i topological linear space, + is continuous, so $x\mapsto x+tz$ is as well. I very much believe $\Phi$ is continuous, but I thought searching would be quicker than trying to prove it and was wrong.
Do you know any sources, counterexamples or can prove something?
Best regards

"I think that $\phi(\operatorname{int}(A)) = \operatorname{int}(\phi(A))$" is correct when $A$ is convex and $\operatorname{int}(A) \neq \emptyset$" I think you should think about $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology and $\phi$ any map of non-full rank and convince yourself that what you wrote can't be right.

Hi Ben. Thx a lot. Of course, you're absolutely right. I changed the interior to relative interior. Any ideas? I am basically looking for anything helpful, so sorry that I do not really know what to ask specifically.

What are the precise definitions of relint, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$?

Hi, relint is the relative interior, so the interior in the subspace topology of $\text{span}(A)$, the linear hull of $A$, so $$\text{relint}(A)={x\in A|\exists V\subseteq X\ \text{open},\ x\in V\cap\text{span}(A)\subseteq A}$$ For $\phi_1$ I am more interested in general results, but for example $\Phi$ would be interesting.
